# Fastest way to merge 2 dictionaries, if one dict's key equals to the other dict's values?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have 2 dictionaries

```
dict1 = {(1,1,1) : ('abc'), (2,2,2) : ('def')} 
dict2 = {('abc') : (1,2,3), ('def') : (4,5,6)}
```

What is the fastest way to produce a dict 3 such that

`dict3 = {(1,1,1):(1,2,3), (2,2,2):(4,5,6)}`?

Comment: Have you tried `{k: dict2[v] for k, v in dict1.items()}`? Should be pretty fast.

Comment: wow it is really that fast! Thanks for the concise and accurate code!!

Comment: @vaultah that should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
dict1 = {(1,1,1) : ('abc'), (2,2,2) : ('def')} 
dict2 = {('abc') : (1,2,3), ('def') : (4,5,6)}
dict3 = {k: dict2[dict1[k]] for k in dict1}

>>> print dict3
{(2, 2, 2): (4, 5, 6), (1, 1, 1): (1, 2, 3)}
```

This iterates over the *keys* of `dict1` and, using the corresponding *value* from `dict1` as a key, looks up the value in `dict2`. The key from `dict1` and the value from `dict2` are then combined to produce a new dictionary.

Note that, in Python 2, this should be slightly faster then using `dict1.items()` because that will build a temporary list. Similarly, iterating over `dict1.iteritems()` returns an iterator which has to be created, but that is neglible. Iterating directly over a dictionary's keys also incurs minimal overhead.

Comment: FWIW `dict1.items()` does not build a list in Python 3.

Comment: @vaultah: yes. I kind of assumed Python 2. I've updated my answer to include your point. Thanks.